# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance?

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, jackson

I have tried everything to read the following JSON string, but I still get the below error.
My JSON string is valid and I think the issue is that the sub element is having problem with the mapping.

Here is my JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "denotations": [
            {
                "id": [
                    "CUI-less"
                ],
                "obj": "disease",
                "span": {
                    "begin": 31,
                    "end": 41
                }
            }
        ],
        "elapsed_time": {
            "ner": 2.759,
            "normalization": 0.002,
            "tmtool": 0.148,
            "total": 2.91
        },
        "logits": {
            "disease": [
                [
                    {
                        "end": 41,
                        "id": "CUI-less",
                        "start": 31
                    },
                    0.999957799911499
                ]
            ],
            "drug": [],
            "gene": [],
            "species": []
        },
        "project": "BERN",
        "sourcedb": "PubMed",
        "sourceid": "2832773",
        "text": "Absence of humoral immunity to poliovirus in vaccinated individuals.",
        "timestamp": "Thu Aug 06 13:42:27 +0000 2020"
    }
]
```

My Java POJO (Logit's class)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "disease",
    "drug",
    "gene",
    "species"
})
public class Logits {

    @JsonProperty("disease")
    private List<List<Disease>> disease = null;
    @JsonProperty("drug")
    private List<Object> drug = null;
    @JsonProperty("gene")
    private List<Object> gene = null;
    @JsonProperty("species")
    private List<Object> species = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("disease")
    public List<List<Disease>> getDisease() {
        return disease;
    }

    @JsonProperty("disease")
    public void setDisease(List<List<Disease>> disease) {
        this.disease = disease;
    }

    @JsonProperty("drug")
    public List<Object> getDrug() {
        return drug;
    }

    @JsonProperty("drug")
    public void setDrug(List<Object> drug) {
        this.drug = drug;
    }

    @JsonProperty("gene")
    public List<Object> getGene() {
        return gene;
    }

    @JsonProperty("gene")
    public void setGene(List<Object> gene) {
        this.gene = gene;
    }

    @JsonProperty("species")
    public List<Object> getSpecies() {
        return species;
    }

    @JsonProperty("species")
    public void setSpecies(List<Object> species) {
        this.species = species;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

I did even try `String[][] disease` but it still fails to parse.

Parsing Code:

```
String denotations = restTemplate.getForObject("http://com/text",String.class);
System.out.println(denotations);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
BernOBJ denoObj = mapper.readValue(denotations, BernOBJ.class);
System.out.println(denoObj);
```

**Stacktrace**

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `com.goodyzain.bern.models.BernOBJ` out of
> START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (String)"[
> {
> "denotations": [
> {
> "id": [
> "CUI-less"
> ],
> "obj": "disease",
> "span": {
> "begin": 31,
> "end": 41
> }
> }
> ],
> "elapsed_time": {
> "ner": 2.759,
> "normalization": 0.002,
> "tmtool": 0.148,
> "total": 2.91
> },
> "logits": {
> "disease": [
> "[truncated 555 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1468)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1242)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1190)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:604)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:190)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4482)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3402)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]     at
> com.goodyzain.bern.BernAPIController.getUsersById(BernAPIController.java:41)
> ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_252]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_252]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_252]   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_252]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_252]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]

Comment: Could you also add the stacktrace of the error and the piece of code where you parse JSON?

Comment: @Sergei i have added the stacktrace & parsing code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current error that you have:

`Cannot deserialize instance of com.goodyzain.bern.models.BernOBJ out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: (String)"[ {`

means that you have a JSON array of objects (starting with `[{...`), but try to parse it into a single object:

```java
BernOBJ denoObj = mapper.readValue(denotations, BernOBJ.class);
```

An array is usually supposed to be parsed into a list of values, e.g. like this:

```java
List<BernOBJ> denoObj = mapper.readValue(denotations, 
  mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, BernObj.class));
```

Also, your `List<List<Disease>>` list doesn't exactly contain `Disease` objects, it contains an object and a `double` value:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "end": 41,
            "id": "CUI-less",
            "start": 31
        },
        0.999957799911499
    ]
]
```

I'm not sure if there's always an object and a numeric value there, and what it means, but you could do the following. Create an additional class, e.g. `DiseasePair`, and map it like this:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "disease", "numericValue" })
class DiseasePair {

    private Disease disease;

    private Double numericValue;

}
```

Then change your `List<List<Disease>>` field type to `List<DiseasePair>`.

Comment: "[truncated 556 chars]; line: 29, column: 21] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.goodyzain.bern.models.BernOBJ["logits"]->com.goodyzain.bern.models.Logits["disease"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.ArrayList[1])

Comment: @goodyzain I've updated the answer to address this error.

Comment: `objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, MyObject.class)` helped me with my problem of reading values from "MyObject"s in a JSON-file and getting them into an ArrayList with "MyObject"s. - ArrayList<MyObject>. Thanks!