# Cannot Deserialize a JSON Array

Tags: deserialization, rest-assured

Iam trying to store this JSON Response in an Object

```
[
    {
        "id": 52,
        "disponibilita": 1,
        "prezzo": 9
    }
]
```

This is an Array and i am Creating a POJO Clss for it

```
private  String id ; 
private String prezzo ; 
private String  disponibilita ;
private String titolo;
```

In the main Method i am trying to create a object for the pojo class and deserialize it

```
poj = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("customerId", "xxx").header("S2S-Authorization", res4).expect()
                .defaultParser(Parser.JSON).when()
                .get("xxx").then()
                .log().all().extract().response().as(pojode.class);

        List<String> myList  = poj.getAction();
        
        System.out.println(myList);
```

Getting the Below Error

Exception in thread "main" `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of` Practise.pojode `out of START_ARRAY token`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285033/com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-mismatchedinputexception-cannot-deserialize)

Comment: Hi Harsh yes but i wanted to know specifically in RestAssured Terms
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map json array `[]` to Java array or Collection.

```java
pojode[] poj = given()...as(pojode[].class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(poj));
```

Comment: Thanks lucas it worked 

i am accessing the values in the JSON by mentioned the index where the key is present